# LARAVEL 5.6 - error Trying to get property 'nsc' of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I want to echo value of NSC from table Group Class but i get this error **Trying to get property 'nsc' of non-object**

[Table Item Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv35X.png)

[Table Group Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV4R4.png)

**Model Item Name**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ItemName extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tbl_item_name';
    protected $fillable = [
        'inc', 
        'item_name', 
        'short_name', 
        'definition_eng', 
        'definition_ind'
    ];

    public function GroupClass()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\GroupClass', 'nsc', 'inc');
    }
}
```

**Model Group Class**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GroupClass extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tbl_group_class';
    protected $fillable = [
        'inc', 
        'nsc', 
        'description', 
        'main_group'
    ];

    public function ItemName()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ItemName', 'inc', 'nsc');
    }
}
```

Blade

```
<td>{{ $ItemName->GroupClass->nsc }}</td>
```

Please help to solve this problem, thank you so much

Comment: Post the code showing how you query the models from the database, and how you're passing them to the view.

Comment: show the controller code

Answer (score 0):

You should try this::

**Blade**

```
<td> {{ isset($ItemName->GroupClass) ?  $ItemName->GroupClass->nsc  : '' }} </td>
```

**Model Item Name**

```
public function GroupClass()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('App\GroupClass', 'inc', 'nsc');
}
```

**Model Group Class**

```
public function ItemName()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ItemName', 'nsc', 'inc');
}
```

Comment: didn't success brother

Comment: that's relationship of table is right brother?, im scare that the relationship isn't right